# How to validate a form on local server then send form to an outside server?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, validation

I have an HTML custom form within Wordpress. This form currently is being validated on a different server and I call that other form with the  "post" method.

However, due to spam bots, I need this form to first get validated on my server, so I need to create a custom PHP file that will validate on my server first, then I need to send that data from the form to the other server.

I do not know how to post again within a PHP form???, and how do I keep track of all my form fields so that I don't lose any data from server to server?

Comment: You can use php curl to repost. Or ifs its only to beat bots you could add a field with a question like repeat the answer to question 2 and verify using jQuery. Its very easy to beat if someone wants to but they have to look at your site to figure it out.